# cin >> command doenst work for some reason

Tags: c++, cin

I'm building a simple program that manages employee info, but I'm experiencing some weird issue with the `cin >>` command, because every time I build the project I get one error only for one `cin >>`.

[image]

Comment: You're missing a semicolon (`;`) after the initialization of `hourly_wage`.

Comment: Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question; which gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted.

Comment: try setting name to string name = "";

Comment: Actually, I think it could be perhaps you're missing the ";" after hourly_wage like @Mureinik stated.

Comment: I never understand why someone would rather take a screenshot, save it, find a place to upload it and then fill out the image info here rather than just copying the code and pasting it and doing a little formatting if needed. Also, it's telling you exactly what the error is.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot a `;` on the previous line:

```cpp
double hourly_wage = 23.50 // <-- ; missing here
```